# How to distinguish between class and static methods in Python and return a Boolean

Tags: python

Similar to [How to distinguish an instance method, a class method, a static method or a function in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947151/how-to-distinguish-an-instance-method-a-class-method-a-static-method-or-a-func), I would like to determine whether a given method is a class method or a static method.

In that answer it is described how to print the `type` in order to determine this. For example,

```
class Resource(object):
    @classmethod
    def parse_class(cls, string):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def parse_static(string):
        pass

# I would like to turn these print statements into Booleans
print type(Resource.__dict__['parse_class'])
print type(Resource.__dict__['parse_static'])
```

prints the output

```
<type 'classmethod'>
<type 'staticmethod'>
```

I would like to take this one step further, however, and write a Boolean expression for whether a method is a class or static method.

Any ideas how to go about this? (I've had a look at the [types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html) module but none of the types seem like `classmethod` or `staticmethod`).

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but do you simply want to assign the type of a static method to a variable in order to compare your methods to it? `type(staticmethod(None))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keywords `staticmethod` and `classmethod` represent the homonymous types:

```
In [1]: staticmethod.__class__
Out[1]: type

In [2]: type(staticmethod)
Out[2]: type

In [3]: classmethod.__class__
Out[3]: type

In [4]: type(classmethod)
Out[4]: type
```

So that means you can use them to compare the statement you are printing in your example:

```
In [5]: class Resource(object):
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def parse_class(cls, string):
   ...:         pass
   ...: 
   ...:     @staticmethod
   ...:     def parse_static(string):
   ...:         pass
   ...:     

 In [6]: print type(Resource.__dict__['parse_class']) == classmethod
 True

 In [7]: print type(Resource.__dict__['parse_static']) == staticmethod
 True
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The types are simply `classmethod` and `staticmethod`, so if you want to perform `type` or `isinstance` checks, `classmethod` and `staticmethod` are the types to use.

Answer (score 1):

The `inspect` module seems to give the desired result:

```
import inspect

inspect.ismethod(Resource.parse_class)
inspect.ismethod(Resource.parse_static)
```

The first returns `True`, while the latter returns `False`.

Or using `types`:

```
import types

isinstance(Resource.parse_class, MethodType)
isinstance(Resource.parse_static, MethodType)
```

Comment: Why does it only *seem* to give the desired result?

Comment: That's probably not doing what you think it is. The descriptor protocol resolves `Resource.parse_static` to the actual `parse_static` function defined in the class body, while `Resource.parse_class` resolves to a bound method object. It's kind of a fluke that things work out this way, and it's not a very clear way to accomplish the desired objective.

Comment: @user2358112: `type(Resource.parse_class)` -> `instancemethod` vs `type(Resource.parse_static)` -> `function`

Comment: If you want the second Boolean to also be `True`, you should do `type(Resource.parse_static) == types.FunctionType`.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
isinstance(vars(Resource)['parse_class'], classmethod)
isinstance(vars(Resource)['parse_static'], staticmethod)
```

And using `vars(my_object)` is just a cleaner way of accessing `my_object.__dict__`